# Process start time with time zone

Tags: process, ps, timestamps, timezone

I'm trying to identify if a file is created after starting the process or not. I'm getting the process start time using command `ps -f -p PID -o lstart=`. This gives me a result such as `Fri May  5 09:15:35 2017` that doesn't have any time zone information.

On the other hand, file system gives me dates with timezone. When I compare dates I get the wrong result. Example:

- process start: `2017-05-05 10:26:57 +0000 UTC`
- file modified: `2017-05-05 10:26:57.679508679 +0200 CEST`

Is it possible to get the process start time with a different format, for instance as unix date? (Having milliseconds would help, too)

Context: I'm running the `ps` command from a go application and parsing the outcome.

Comment: There is no way to tell `ps` to use other start date/time format than the ones defined (bsdstart, lstart, start, start_time). But when the process is started, the folder `/proc/$pid` is created (well, with all current linux versions I deal with; don't know about other *nixes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs). So `ls -ld /proc/$pid` should give you the time in the same format as the file modification time. If you use `--time-style` option with ls, you are able to define the format as you want.

Comment: stat /proc/$pid/cmdline

Comment: @ridgy and Archemar, no, the mtime of /proc/pid/files is the time those files were instantiated. Not the start time of the process. See [Get process age from command line](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/241869) or [When was a process started](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/62162)

Comment: The actual start time is field 22 of `/proc/$PID/stat`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38740102/6372809 and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html (look for `starttime`)

Comment: In any case, the start time of a process doesn't have to be (and never is exactly) the time that process executed the command it is currently running.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, you mean time of `fork()` vs. time of `exec()` ?

Comment: @Stéphane Thanks, you are right, I never stop learning!

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes. For instance in `sh -c 'sleep 10; exec env ps -o lstart -p "$$"'` run from my `zsh` prompt, that process that `ps` reports is first running `zsh` (for a very short time after the fork), then 10 seconds later, `env`, then `ps`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the explanation. I'm keeping the pid of the parent process when I start it. So in my particular case, I don't have this kind of complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file system doesn't give you a time with timezone, it's whatever command that you use to display that time in a human friendly format that may give you a timezone if it chooses to display the time in local time (as specified by `/etc/localtime`, `$TZ` or other).

Generally, timestamps on Unix are expressed in a way that is irrelevant of timezones. The unix epoch time is the number of seconds (seconds expressed as the 86400th part of a day, so varying in length but more useful for calendar calculation) since a precise event in history (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, an unambiguous time). Timezones only come into the picture when displaying a date in a calendar format to a human.

```
ps -o lstart= -p "$pid"
date -r /some/file
```

both give you the local time. `date` might output the timezone offset or not depending on the locale. If you want the UTC time, run them under `TZ=UTC0`:

```
TZ=UTC0 ps -o lstart= -p "$pid"
TZ-UTC0 date -r /some/file # or use date -u
```

GNU `date` is able to parse the date reported by `ps`, so you can convert it to any format, like the unix epoch time:

```
(export TZ=UTC0
date -d "$(ps -o lstart -p "$pid") +%s
date -r /some/file +%s)
```

(above using UTC time. It would also work with whatever the local time is in your environment except for one hour in the year where a time output without TZ indication is ambiguous (in zones that implement DST)).

In any case, the start time of a process doesn't have to be (and never is exactly) the time that process executed the command it is currently running. For instance:

```
$ TZ=UTC0 strace -qtt -e execve sh -c 'sleep 3; exec env ps -o lstart= -p "$$"'
10:27:24.877397 execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "sleep 3; exec env ps -o lstart= "...], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
10:27:27.882553 execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "ps", "-o", "lstart=", "-p", "9397"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
10:27:27.885272 execve("/bin/ps", ["ps", "-o", "lstart=", "-p", "9397"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
Fri May  5 10:27:24 2017
```

That 9397 process is running 4 commands in its life time: `strace` (forked there), `sh`, `env`, `ps`. The time reported by `ps` corresponds to the time when it was forked by `strace`, not when it executed `ps`.

If you want to get subsecond precision (up to `1/$(getconf CLK_TCK)`), with `zsh`, you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
tick=$(getconf CLK_TCK)
(echo $((EPOCHREALTIME + (${${=$(</proc/self/stat)##*)}[20]}. -
          ${${=$(</proc/$pid/stat)##*)}[20]})/tick)))
```

That is we get the start time of the $pid and of a newly created subshell (that's the 20th fields after the last occurrence of a `)` character in `/proc/pid/stat` expressed in CLK_TCK in modern versions of Linux), divide the difference by `CLK_TCK` and add to the current time.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, missing timezone was defaulted to UTC, so adding the `TZ=UTC0` solved my problem. Generally speaking, time zone handling is a little different in both cases as ` date -r file` returns `Fri May  5 14:26:26 CEST 2017` and `TZ=UTC0 ps -o lstart= -p pid` returns `Fri May  5 07:15:35 2017`

Comment: @rosencreuz, yes but `Fri May 5 07:15:35 2017` was `Fri May 5 07:15:35 2017 CEST` that is, still a date in local time, not UTC, even if `ps` doesn't give you a `CEST` or `+0200` to indicate that it is indeed a local time. With `TZ=UTC0 ps -o lstart= -p "$pid"`, `ps` is still giving a time in local time, but this time, we're telling it that the local time is UTC.